# Material UI's Stepper Component's error state showing unwanted icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

Im using Material UI's Stepper component and trying to get the fill of a stepper that is in its error state to be red.

For reference, here is the Stepper component in Material UI's docs.

[image]

So im trying to show an error state. Material UI's has an error prop that will show the error state, however, I dont want the icon provided.

[image]

I just want it to be like any other stepper, just with a red background.

Is there any way I can get rid of that icon, and just show a red fill?

Been search all over but seems like no one really asked about this.

Here is my code:

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={this.determineFormStep()} connector={<StepConnector />} className={classes.stepper}>
          {formLabels.map((label) => {
            return (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel
                  error
                  StepIconProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.step,
                      completed: classes.completed,
                      active: classes.active,
                      error: classes.error,
                      disabled: classes.disabled
                    }
                  }}>
                  <div className={classes.stepLabelRoot}>
                    <Typography className={classes.label}>
                      {label.label}
                    </Typography>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel1}
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel2}
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sublabel}>
                      {label.sublabel3}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </StepLabel>
              </Step>);
          })}
        </Stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs for StepLabel](https://mui.com/api/step-label/) show that it can take an optional `icon` prop, which is a node that overrides the step icon.

As an example, if you wanted to hide the icon entirely you could pass a Fragment element as the icon:

```
<StepLabel
    error
    icon={<></>}
>
    ...
</StepLabel>
```

Or you can change the `StepIconComponent` or `StepIconProps`.

Here is an example turns off the error state on the icon only:

```
<StepLabel
    error
    StepIconProps={ {error: false} }
>
    ...
</StepLabel>
```